# Free for common use

Tags: meaning

Can I say that an application is Free for common use? meaning everyone has access to all features and can use it free of charge unless s/he needs to use it on a large scale. This would require a paid subscription Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why do you think *common* conveys that?

Comment: Do you mean that a single license is free, but multiple licenses aren't?

Comment: Try looking at the terms used on the very large number of websites that provide 'free' software.

Comment: You might say "free for individual use".  But anything you want to carry legal weight needs to be more specifically worded -- if you don't get actual legal advice, at least copy the license agreement of some other work with similar restrictions.  (And we don't give legal advice on SE.)

Answer (score 0):

Open source means Applications or software that are free for common use.

When people start to use these open source applications for their own commercial purposes, they are punishable by law. It will be clearly quoted in the license file of the application or software.

In the license file(doc file),the creator of the application or the software will specify either of the different versions of licenses say GNU GPL(General Public License)or GNU AGPL or APACHE license or MIT license

So, answers are

Free for common use -> open sourced

To tell them that users should pay when they need to use it on a large scale -> licensed